# Alert box is not closing when trying to do so

Tags: javascript, html, css, alert

I've copied this code and the alert box appears but it doesn't seem to close when I click on the "x", here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
     <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>The File will be deleted!
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Librarys:
[this is the way I imported them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qtber.png)

Comment: I've fixed it! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your libraries seems to be the problem this code is working correctly check it

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="container">
      <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
        <strong>Success!</strong> This alert box could indicate a successful or positive action.
      </div>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The course that I'm doing indicated me to save the bootstrap link directly into my project folder, and the same with jquery, I don't know if they're working correctly.

Comment: but it seems that you haven't imported it correctly

Comment: check out the image I added, that's the way I imported it, maybe it's wrong

Comment: can you add **./** before your directories like **./js/bootstrap.js**

Comment: I've fixed it! Thank you

Comment: how did it happened

Answer (score 0):

Did you import **jquery,Bootstrap** correctly (path)  ? It is working for me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
     <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>The File will be deleted!
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think so, the course I'm doing indicated me to save the bootstrap link directly into my project folder, and the same with jquery, I don't know if they're working correctly.

Comment: I see added screenshot,Try something <script src="./js/jquery.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your script tags out of the head-tag and down into the body-tag tag just before the closing body tag.

It's considered bad practice to have the script tags in the head because they might run before the whole DOM has been loaded.

Comment: I've corrected it but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem :- 
you don't include **bootstrap js** file that will do all the work for you

The solution :- 
you should include the file

take a look at this link from the **bootstrap** documentation 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/#dismissing

You'll find this line

> Be sure you’ve loaded the alert plugin, or the compiled Bootstrap JavaScript.

also try to put the script files in the bottom of your HTML

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
     <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>The File will be deleted!
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I've fixed it! Thank you